# Absolutely positioned Div goes out of the screen when the width of the screen gets small

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm making a website like this now for my portfolio. [Link](https://www.wix.com/website-template/view/html/2622?siteId=7e761c3c-729b-4d4e-9dc3-a8242c486f56&metaSiteId=3f62d478-a066-43ee-98e6-3e48600ff893&originUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.wix.com%2Fwebsite%2Ftemplates%3Fcriteria%3DEngineering%2BPortfolio%26page%3D3&tpClick=view_button) 
The box that contains the image of the person doesn't not go out of the screen when you decrease the size of the screen horizontally but mine does. Is there a way to prevent this and make it like the example website?

Another question is I found that a huge blank space is created below the main-box when the width of the screen is less than 900px. I don't know why it happens and how to fix it.

[My website](https://master.d25euvkr5jql42.amplifyapp.com/)

HomeMain.js

```
export class HomeMain extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <div className="main-box">
          <div className="left-main-box"></div>
          <div className="right-main-box"></div>
          <CenterBox />
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

CenterBox.js

```
export class CenterBox extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="main-center-box">
        <div className="left-center-box">left-center</div>
        <div className="right-center-box">right-center</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

App.scss

```
/* Homepage Style */

.main-box {
  height: $main-container-height;
  position: relative;

  .left-main-box {
    height: $main-container-height;
    width: 45%;
    min-width: 400px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #ede7dd;
  }

  .right-main-box {
    display: inline-block;
    height: $main-container-height;
    width: 55%;
    background-color: white;
  }
}

/* Homepage center box style */

.main-center-box {
  position: absolute;
  width: 800px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;

  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

  .left-center-box {
    background-color: #faf7f4;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50%;
    height: 550px;
  }
  .right-center-box {
    background-color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50%;
    height: 550px;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The element that holds the image in the example website is not centered absolute like you did. Instead, a margin is applied that is calculated relative to the viewport width:

```
    margin: 72px 0px 44px calc((100% - 980px) * 0.5);
```

the fourth of the margin values is set by using `calc()` ([Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/calc)) to express a formula, which basically sets the left margin to an increasingly high value on big devices while returning `0` on monitors below 980px width.

As for the second problem: the `.left-main-box` occupies minimum 400px width, and the `.right-main-box` right to it just drops on a new line on small screens. By calculating the width like:

```
.right-main-box {
  width: min(calc(100% - 400px), 55%);
}
```

you get the desired spacing.

Answer (score 0):

You could center the Image element relative to the size of the Image Container, not the body.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
}

.image {
  --size: 100px;
  
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - var(--size) / 2);
  left: calc(50% - var(--size) / 2);
  width: var(--size);
  height: var(--size);
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  container
  <div class="image">
    Image
  </div>
</div>
```